# Identity column problem in SQL replication

Tags: database-replication

How can we transfer primary key (identity column) while replicating a database.

Comment: what do you mean by "transfer" ? what kind of replication and with what dbms ?

Comment: Which database?  What method have you tried so far and what was the error it gave?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the tables IDENTITY_INSERT to on and after everything is done turn it back off again.

SET IDENTITY_INSERT test ON

-- Inserts

SET IDENTITY_INSERT test OFF

But for more info and exceptions check this great article.
http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/the-identity-crisis-in-replication/

Comment: This will not work if you have a permanent replication set up between two server, or if you are replicating two or more tables. Only one table can have IDENTITY_INSERT turned ON at the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking MySQL, a simple export/drop/create process should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "identity" definition on your target table and you can copy directly from the source table. This will only work if the replication is one-way.